# How to handle Galaxy S4 resolution since it's too high for AndEngine RatioResolutionPolicy

Tags: android, andengine

I'm starting with AndEngine following this tutorial:

http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-1.html

But this guy looks like it's using a low resolution device for this test, I'm using a Galaxy S4 with a 1920x1080 resolution, yeah, damn high.

I know the thing about the RatioResolutionPolicy, but even though I'm using 800x480 in my S4 I got 2 white stripes from both sides (LANDSCAPE) like if it wasn't good resized, do I need to include another wallpaper for very high screen resolution devices?

Also, some coordinates that this guy used on the tutorial are bad placed on my S4, How am I supposed to make all devices compatible with this?

ADDING CODE:

```
    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480; 

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.camera);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
        engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
        return engineOptions;
    }
```

Comment: what is your camera hight width?

Comment: my camera hight and width are set to 800 x 480 hardcoded of course. And my S4 is 1920x1080 :/ why that damn high, huh? (updated the post so you can see that piece of code)

Comment: Are the images your are using are compatable to 480X800 or not.You can fix your camera height and width based on resolution you are targeting

Comment: my images are 800x480 yea, like the background main menu one. But... looks like there's no way for 800x480 to adapt to 1920x1080... that's why i'm getting the white stripes on the borders... i was wondering, how am i going to support every single resolution ? :/

Comment: Why your sticking with that policy.You can try other resolution policies like crop, FullScreen...

Comment: Crop, FullScreen? :o can you give me that precious code D: haha

Comment: oh lol "new FillResolutionPolicy()" works really great!

Comment: please take a look at my answer and if you don't understand ask for clarification. You don't need to know every resolution to support it, just calculate the device ratio and then create a camera of that ratio, so andengine will put it in fullscreen without need to crop or distort. This is the natural way. if you force fullscreen without taking care of the ratio, you will have distorted elements (even if the difference is so small that you dont realize) But in some other devices the difference could be greater and user will realize.

Comment: Actually Nicolas Gramlich says, for using FillResolutionPolicy()
`Beware that you have to handle the ratio of the camera to the same ratio as the screen has.`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not the resolution, but the ratio. your camera has a ratio of 1.66, while your device has a ratio of 1.77, that is almost the same, but not the same.

You Need to calculate the ratio. Andengine will project the camera in any device, that's the magic of opengl and the camera, but if the ratio is not the same, it has to put that lines to avoid the image to be cropped or distorted, like when you see a 4:3 movie in a 16:9 tv

The solution would be to have a camera that has the same ratio has the device, so if the ratio is different,  you dont have white stripes, but for example some extra background.

For example, in your case, you get the device size, get the ratio (1920/1080=1.7777) so you create a camera with that ratio. ie:

```
    float device_ratio = DEVICE_HEIGHT/DEVICE_WIDTH;// in this case 1.7777 
    CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800/device_ratio ; /// this will be 450
```

So, you will have a camera of 800x450, and you can have backgrounds of that size (or some bigger that you can crop). This is, you don't have to use images of the full size of the device, but just create a camera of the same size of the device, and create backgrounds that look ok in that camera. You create your world in that 800x450 "canvas", and andengine will project it in the real device. Since the ratio is the same, everything will look ok. nothing cropped, nothing distorted, and no extra lines.

Now you has to think in a more relative way, since your camera will not be always be exactly the same, depending on the device. This is straightforward if you don't have many hardcoded values.

Comment: Tried using a 1920x1080 main menu background i got an error from the app saying http://puu.sh/6cmzt.png lol :(

Comment: You dont need a background that big, actually i dont know how big is a GPU texture, but i thing thats too much. You only need a background that looks good in that aspect ratio, or a background that you can crop and its a little more than your camera, so it is valid for any ratio. But with an small background is enaough, you only need to respect the ratio.

Comment: +1 to @CarlosRobles - it's about the ratio, not the actual size. And you are correct too - don't use 1920x1080 - use something like 1024x576 and keep your textures <= 1024x1024

Comment: Exactly @jmr499485. And also, for a best performance, you can keep track of where you put the image in the texture and use the free space  to put more images, do you can use as much as you can of the 1024×1024

Comment: the other side of it is - if you design it at that aspect ratio of the S4, it will look different on other devices that have a different aspect ratio. The ideal solution would be to design for the 3 common aspect ratios and determine the one needed at run-time to load the appropriate assets.

Comment: It can be ok if everything is relative, or if you choose a good inner ratio for the scene, that is and the center no matter what the camera ratio is, and you have more or less background depending on the device. Actually the decision on this depends of the specific game and this is one step forward

Comment: WHITE BACKGROUND STRIPES: These are caused by the default application theme. Try using Style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen. Then you will get the more desirable black letterboxing when your aspect ratio does not match the device.