# AndEngine - standard screen size 800,480 does not fill Galaxy s3

Tags: size, screen, andengine

I am a beginner andengine developer.

I have read on andengine forum and other tutorials that the main screen size should be 800 to 480 (horizontal). On the Galaxy S2 everything is correct but with my S3 the screen border on the left and right side is "cut" white and the same think on Galaxy s6500 with the upper and bottom border. Do I need to set the screen size for each device? How can I change the color of the border?

Comment: I have created camera with FillResolutionPolicy() and after that everything worked fine.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963751/how-to-handle-galaxy-s4-resolution-since-its-too-high-for-andengine-ratioresolu/20963881#comment31506824_20963881 for some more info on how to handle this